# How shall I grep a multi-line pattern in a pdf file and in a text file?

Tags: grep, pdf, pdfgrep

In the output of `less my.pdf`,  a string `image
   not
available` appears multiple times, for example:

```
... Lastly, what remains to
^L image
   not
available
^L     Implementations and Systems
```

I would like to grep the string in the pdf file, for example, by `pdfgrep`.
But `pdfgrep  -ni "image not available" my.pdf` doesn't find anything. What shall I do then?

Related question: Since `pdfgrep` has similar user interface to `grep`, how does `grep` handle a pattern which spans more than one lines?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK `grep` doesn't - unless your `grep` implementation provides a null terminated input option (`-z`) allowing you to fake it by slurping the whole file. OTOH `pcregrep` does, using the `-M` switch. I don't have a suitable PDF to test it on, but I'd try something like `pdfgrep -Pn '(?s)image\s+?not\s+?available`

Comment: Thanks. `pdfgrep -Pn '(?s)image\s+?not\s+?available' my.pdf` works.

Comment: Thanks. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457844/how-can-i-get-the-page-numbers-only-of-a-pattern-in-a-pdf-file-regardless-if-th

Comment: ... FWIW you probably don't *need* to use PCRE, you just need a regex that matches the newlines - either implicitly (like PCRE with the `(?s)` modifier) or explicitly (using `\n` where required)